# PHP equivalent to this Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, php

JavaScript:

```
var chartData = [];
     for (var i = 0; i< data.prices.length; i++)
      {
        chartData.push
        ({
        "date": data.prices[i][0],
        "value": data.prices[i][1],
        "volume": data.total_volumes[i][1]
        });  
      }
```

My attempt (PHP):

```
$chartData = [];
    $length = count($data->prices);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)     
    {
    $chartData[] = array($data->prices[$i][0],$data->prices[$i][1],$data->total_volumes[$i][1]);
    }
```

I'm trying to handle data from an API server side with php and then encode the data for javascript. I'm stuck converting this javascript snippet to PHP at the "date": "value": and "volume": I don't know what the equivalent to this would be in PHP. It looks as though they are labels in javascript to the data being pushed to the array? How do I give the data being pushed to the array the same labels in PHP?

Comment: Do you have any error ?

Comment: Change $chartData = []; to $chartData = array(); and see if that helps.

Comment: It is always useful to see at least an example of the input data and an example of what you want output from the code

Comment: Are you using PHP 5 or 7? PHP 5 doesn't accept `chartData = []` but rather `chartData = array()`

Comment: You have everything you need in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were pretty close you can define keys and values in PHP by doing:

```
$chartData[] = array(
   "date"   => $data->prices[$i][0],
   "value"  => $data->prices[$i][1],
   "volume" => $data->total_volumes[$i][1]
);
```

Comment: And of course “array(“ and “)” can be replaced with “[“ and “]” respectively which is the shorthand version for defining arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "clever" way:

```
$chartData = array_map(function($price,$volume) {
    return array(
        "date" => $price[0],
        "value" => $price[1],
        "volume" => $volume[1]
    );
}, $data->prices, $data->total_volumes);
```

Comment: I would say fancy rather than clever, as it's not any more clever than any other way of doing it

Comment: This is actually a very good way of doing it. I would recommend OP to research the significant differences between closures in JavaScript and php particularly regarding scope though as it can be really frustrating if you don’t know beforehand.

Comment: @Christopher Frustrating yes... until you discover `use ($scopevar)` :D